# laravel 8 store request with foreign key user_id not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I would like to store the corresponding logged in user when adding a new School data. What I'm trying to do is store the logged in user_id in the schools table, in order to know on who added the school data. I have a users table already, which will establish the relation in the schools table.

My goal is when an admin is logged in, he/she can see all of the School records, otherwise if it's a user, then only fetch the records he/she added. The problem is that I can't figure out on when and where to insert the user_id data during the store request as I'm getting an error "user id field is required". Here's what I've tried so far:

**Migration:**

```
class CreateSchoolsTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('school_name');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

**School Model:**

```
class School extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['school_name', 'user_id'];


    public function User() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

**Store Request:**

```
class StoreSchoolRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'school_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class SchoolController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreSchoolRequest $request) {
        $school_data = $request->validated();
        $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $school_data['user_id'] = $user_id;

        School::create($school_data );

        return Redirect::route('schools.index');
    }
}
```

Any inputs will be of big help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has elegant way to bind authenticated user_id. Remove user_id from request class and chaining method. Also setup relationship from User model to School Model

Form Request Class

```php
class StoreSchoolRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'school_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];
    }
}
```

User Model

```php
protected $fillable = ['school_name', 'user_id'];
...
// new line
public function schools() {
   return $this->hasMany(School::class);
}
```

Your Controller

```php
class SchoolController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreSchoolRequest $request) {
        auth()->user()->schools()->create($request->validated());
        return Redirect::route('schools.index');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

Since user_id value is school name (based on image link from comment), probably there's something wrong either in User or School model. Here the quick fix

Your Controller

```php
class SchoolController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreSchoolRequest $request) {
        auth()->user()->schools()->create(
            array_merge(
                $request->validated(), 
                ['user_id' => auth()->id()]
            )
         );
        return Redirect::route('schools.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, one last question, the stored data in the schools table isn't the user_id, how to fix that?

Comment: what you gonna store at there? in general, RDBMS store foreignId like user_id

Comment: it should be the user_id, but I'm getting the school name at the user_id column in the schools table

Comment: It's like:
________________
|user_id            |
-----------------
|Tes,t School    |
|Test,t School 2|

Comment: can you provide image? imgur seems good to me. i dont quiet understand

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time, here's the image https://ibb.co/D4zPxFd

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'created_by' and 'updated_by' fields to your table. so you can register in these fields when additions or updates are made.
Then you can see who has added or updated from these fields.

```
class School extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['school_name', 'user_id', 'created_by', 'updated_by'];


    public function User() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The timestamps() are already added on the migration. The problem is that I can't insert the user_id on the store function.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller part is correct but since you get the logged in user, you wont be having `user_id` in the request. So you should remove the rules about `user_id` from your `StoreSchoolRequest`.

```
class StoreSchoolRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'school_name' => 'required|string|max:255'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Will remove it. Would also like to ask on how to validate the foreign key data? Is it on the controller part?

Comment: You won’t validate it, if you want to be 100% sure you can use the “auth” middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here ..

> $school_data = $request->validated();

Since you are using $request->validated()..

You have to safe()->merge user_id into it , [here Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#working-with-validated-input) : .

$validated = $request->safe()->merge(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);

Then put this $validated into create query , Thanks. –

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The \Auth::user()->id is working upon checking, the problem is that on the insertion of user_id on the request.

Comment: $school_data = $request->validated(); Since you are using $request->validated().. You have to safe()->merge user_id into it , here Docs : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#working-with-validated-input.            $validated = $request->safe()->merge(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]); ,Then put this $validated into create query , thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Really appreciate your help! One last thing, do I need to remove user_id validation in the store request since it fails?

Comment: Yep ... No Need to add user_id in the request. Because you are getting it in the controller and it's already an authenticated user , thanks . I Edited My answer plz mark it as Correct , thanks...